# Python: Fitting non-linear function into surface

Tags: scipy, data-fitting

I've got an error gauss function erfc(x) which I need to fit into my data of surface.
Whole equation is:

```
 Z = Z_0 * erfc(x / 2*sqrt(D*t))
```

I know from data Z, Z_0, x, t ... the only parameter I am looking for is D. Using curve_fit is fine for single lines but I need to find only one constant parameter D for whole surface.
The surface looks like this 
[image: surface]].
Any ideas, please? Thanks

Comment: Are both `x` and `t` independent variables?

Comment: Yes, it's position and time.

Comment: Note: the argument of `erfc` should be `x / (2*sqrt(D*t))`?

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example that demonstrates a multivariate `curve_fit`. Note that I used a class object to store the parameter `Z0`, but there are other ways to do this (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49813481/1510542)).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import erfc

# Class to contain model and parameters
class fitClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # Model with unknown parameter D
    def func(self, p, D):
        x, t = p
        Z = self.Z0 * erfc(x / 2*np.sqrt(D*t))
        return Z

# Instantiate class and define parameters
inst = fitClass()
inst.Z0 = 1.0
D = 10.0
Nx = int(1e2)
Nt = int(1e1)

# Independent variables
x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, Nx)
t = np.linspace(1.0, 5.0, Nt)

X, T = np.meshgrid(x, t)

# Merge independent variables
xdata = np.vstack([X.reshape(-1), T.reshape(-1)])

# Synthetic ydata (noisy measurement)
noise = 0.5*(np.random.rand(Nx*Nt)-0.5)
Z = inst.func(xdata, D)
Z_noisy = Z + noise

# Fit model to data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(inst.func, xdata, Z_noisy)
D_fit = popt[0]
print(D_fit)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks helpful. However, my Z data are 2D array. When you look at the attached figure. One axis is position "x", the second horizontal is time "t" and the third one vertical is Z.

Comment: The plot in your question is the visualisation of your function on a grid, but your data are discrete measurements? I.e. for each value of `x`, there is one corresponding `t` and `Z`? Perhaps you can give a little more context in which to interpret your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. These are data from Scanning Probe Microscopy and data are discrete, so one horizontal axis is time, let's say (0, 2, 4, ... seconds). The second horizontal axis is position and vertical line is Z=f(x,t). Depending on this, each combination of x and t has some specific Z value. If I fit it good enough I can find value for parameter D which should be constant for whole surface and Z_0 is maximum of Z. Did I make it clearer?

Comment: The order of the data should not matter, so `xdata` can be represented by 2 1D arrays instead of 2 structured matrices. I have updated my solution, in which `X` and `T` represent the grid data you would obtain from your SPM analysis.